# Intersect in PostGIS

Tags: postgis, postgresql, intersection

I have two geometries and I want to write the information from one geometry into the other geometry, but only where they `intersect`. Sometimes, a geometry is intersected with to different geometries (see my screenshot). The yellow geometry is intersected by two geometries (thick black line). The resulting table should contain the yellow geometry twice, with the two different information from the intersecting geometries.

[image: screenshot]

I tried

```
CREATE TABLE myTable AS
SELECT g.a, g.b, g.geom, t.c, t.d
FROM green_geometries g
LEFT OUTER JOIN thickBlackLine t
ON ST_Intersects(ST_PointOnSurface(g.geom), t.geom);
```

However, the resulting table only contains the yellow geometry once, with only one information from the intersecting geometry added to it.

---

*edit: `thickBlackLine t` is a a table, containing many polygons. In the screenshot here you only see the outline (thickBlackline) of the polygon.
Maybe on the screenshot here it becomes more clear. I am trying to perform a Spatial Join on polygons, not line and polygon(s)!

[image: screenshot 2]

Comment: The "intersects" relationship between a point and a line is fraught with complications, when you compound it with the centroid of a polygon, you're really off in the weeds.  Have you tried writing the SQL for the problem you've described in the body of the text?  The query you've provided is nothing like the UPDATE (or even the FROM subselect) required.

Comment: @Vince that might come across not correct here. The thick black line is the border of a polygon. Basically the "north" of the black line is a polygon with a geometry `geom` in the table `thickBlackLine` and the "south" of the black line is a polygon with a geometry `geom` in the table `thickBlackLine`

Comment: Please **edit the question** to clarify that the object described as a "line" *isn't* a line.

Comment: Intersecting with the centroid still makes absolutely no sense if you want two rows returned. If you rendered the centroids in the question you'd understand your results.

Comment: This is really still confusing as to what you want. You're using a CTAS in your example. Can you build a table using the same method that has simplified input data, and your desired output data?

Comment: You say *Sometimes, a geometry is "intersected" with [two] different geometries (see my screenshot)*. That's not GIS terminology. Sometimes a geometry is *overlapped* by another geometry (intersects) and other times a geometry is *composed* of two other other geometry that share a border. That's all you have. I'm not sure what your line is trying to represent. If it's two separate geometries color them separate (for illustration), if it's overlapped by some geometry north of the line, normally you show this with a venn-coloration. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Venn_diagram

Comment: @EvanCarroll The bottom layer (green) is a table with many polygons. The top layer (here colored in the second screenshot) is also a table with many polygons. I want to write the information from the top layer into the bottom layer. However, when the bottom polygon is overlayed/intersected by two polygons (from the top layer), I want a duplicated row of the corresponding bottom polygon with the two different information from the top layer in it.

Comment: @Vince Working with the the query above and getting rid of the `ST_PointOnSurface` should preserve all the geometries of `green_geometries` that are not intersected by `thickBlackLine`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you right your problem is the pointonsurface.

That point will intersect only 1 polygon in table t. Use the full polygon instead. Just remove the pointonsurface function.

Comment: That also preserves the geometries of the green underlying polygons which are not intersected by one of the overlying ones?

Comment: Yes, the left join should give one of each from left table even if there is no intersection